# Splitting a 2 digit number into 10's and 1's in python

Tags: python, split, modulo

I am writing a program where the user must input a number between 0 and 100. Then the program should split the number into 10's and 1's. So if the user inputs 23, the program would return 2 and 3. If the user input 4, the program would return 0 and 4. This is what I have for numbers less than 10, but I'm not sure how to handle 2 digit numbers using the modulo operator.

```
def split():
    number = int(raw_input("Enter a number between 0 and 100:"))
    if number <10:
        tens = 0
        ones = number
        total = tens + ones
        print "Tens:", tens
        print "Ones:", ones
        print "Sum of", tens, "and", ones, "is", total

split()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `divmod` function.

```
>>> a, b = divmod(23, 10)
>>> a, b
(2, 3)
>>> print "Tens: %d\nOnes: %d" % divmod(23, 10)
Tens: 2
Ones: 3
```

Don't know about `divmod`? `help` is your friend!

```
>>> help(divmod)
Help on built-in function divmod in module __builtin__:

divmod(...)
    divmod(x, y) -> (quotient, remainder)

    Return the tuple ((x-x%y)/y, x%y).  Invariant: div*y + mod == x.
```